# Do I need to close files I perform File.getName() on?

Tags: java, file

I'll be having lot of files in a directory. I'll be just getting the file names using `File.getName()` and log them to a log file. I presume, I don't need to close the file since I'm not doing any read/write operation in it.

Is this correct?

Comment: If you want to list the files in a directory, you may use [`File#list()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29)

Comment: If you open a file then you need to close it, but the `File` class doesn't represent an open file, it just represents a path.

Comment: got it. thank you all for your reply, thanks.

Comment: If the answers helped you, please rather upvote them and - what is even more important - accept the best one.

Answer (score 42):

You never have to close `File`s, because it is basically a representation of a path. Only Streams and Readers/Writers. In fact, `File` does not even have a `close()` method.

Answer (score 6):

```
Only resources needed to be close.
```

In java API there is a interface [Closeable Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), those classes implement this interface they need to be close after use.

```
close() //method is in that interface..
```

And use of **close** is

```
It closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. 
If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.
```

`File` is no need to be close

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.  Note that there is no `File.close()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. When you open a file by creating a `FileInputStream` or a `FileOutputStream`, you must close the stream at the end.