# close, destructor and finalize: Java contradictions

Tags: java, class, file-io, code-cleanup, finalize

I have the following code, which works nicely in my class reading a file line by line.

```
 try {  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
             // read the file
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

But if I try to add the command ***close***, for after the file was finished reading, then I got the error:

```
    in.close();

Error:(131, 9) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable in
location: class ReadFile
```

I searched about cleaning objects after use and the need to close files before your program ends. And found several posts on this for Java, but many are very contradictory. The point is that in the end I just get very confused.

Am I wrong, or Java programming is a little bit fuzzy and messy? I mean, there is apparently no real use of [***destructor***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171952/is-there-a-destructor-for-java), the use of [***finalize***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158174/why-would-you-ever-implement-finalize) is very questionable, and the use of [***close***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211760/do-i-need-to-close-files-i-perform-file-getname-on) is also suggested as unnecessary. Some of the posts on these issues are contradictory and non-conclusive.

So, how to proceed here? In the case I really need to close the file, how to get rid of this error message? Is it really dispensable and unnecessary to close files? What about cleaning up class instances for the the program finishes?

Comment: At which place you're calling `in.close()`? Remember in Java, scope matters.

Comment: @PradeepSimha - just after the closing of catch{}

Comment: Declare `in` outside of your try block.

Comment: @Vash - it is not a duplicate, as the post you mention doesn't address the issues I am quoting here, neither the command "close"

Comment: There is no destructor in Java. The finalize() method is indeed not something you should use or rely upon. And close() is absolutely necessary to call. Use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, and learn about variable scopes. This is a notion that is important in every language.

Comment: @PradeepSimha - it just give another error if I follow your suggestion.

Comment: Also if you have JDK 7 you can use `try-with-resources` statement instead of writing the ugly try-catch-finally.

Comment: @EmmaYazzie What's that error?

Comment: @JBNizet, not *every* language ... as I recall, PostScript doesn't have scope, per se, though you can fake it, and I don't *think* TeX does either.

Comment: @JBNizet - Thanks! very insightful your comments. I really appreciate that.

Comment: @dfeuer: OK. In *almost* every language :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the error because you have defined variable `in` inside the try block, so it is not visible in catch/finally/or anywhere outside that try. Move the declaration outside try:

Change this

```
try {  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
```

to

```
FileInputStream in = null;
try {  in = new FileInputStream(filename);
```

Comment: Do not use comments to argue about mechanics of the site.

Comment: @JunedAhsan - that solved the error message.

Answer (score 5):

you may be closing `in.close()` out side try block so obviously you will get error because `in` is defined in try block which is local.

Better to use [try with resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so you need not to manually close file stream

Comment: thank you. Using "try with resource" is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you must call the `close()` method inside the `finally` block, after the `null` check.
And for that you need to declare the variable `in` outside the `try` block.

Calling the `close()` method in `finally` block ensures that it is called irrespective of whether an Exception is thrown or not by the code in `try` block.

**EDIT :** This is when you are using Java 6 or earlier version. For Java 7 and higher you could use *try with resource* as suggested by @JqueryLearner

Comment: try-with-resources is better still. It's easier to get it right and harder to get it wrong, and I think there may be other advantages too.

Comment: I meant this for Java 6 or earlier version. Edited my answer. Thanks